# Generate table based on number of rows, columns in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

How do I generate a table in jQuery based on a given number of rows and columns?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use nested for loops, create elements and append them to one another. Here's a very simple example that demonstrates creating DOM elements, and appending them.

You'll notice that the `$('<tag>')` syntax will create an element, and you can use the [appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) method to, well, do exactly that. Then, you can add the resulting table to the DOM.

```
var rows = 5; //here's your number of rows and columns
var cols = 5;
var table = $('<table><tbody>');
for(var r = 0; r < rows; r++)
{
    var tr = $('<tr>');
    for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++)
        $('<td>some value</td>').appendTo(tr); //fill in your cells with something meaningful here
    tr.appendTo(table);
}

table.appendTo('body'); //Add your resulting table to the DOM, I'm using the body tag for example
```

Comment: Excellent script. Just need to know how to use specific <div id="tbl"> instead of 'body' table.appendTo('body');   please help.