# Create one list item for each year using JQuery

Tags: jquery, foreach

I am building a web app that is a visual representation of data sorted by year, and currently have an ordered list of years in the html, i.e.:

```
<ol id="years">
    <li>1900</li>
    <li>1901</li>
    <li>1902</li>
```

…

```
    <li>1950</li>
</ol>
```

I would prefer that the list was automatically generated on page load by javascript, as it's likely that the year range will change over time, and I don't want to risk the javascript and HTML getting out of sync.

For other functions I am already declaring variables `firstYear` and `lastYear` that match up to the first and last items in that list, i.e.:

```
var firstYear = 1900;
var lastYear = 1950;
```

I've tried to base some code on what looks like [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347542/generate-table-based-on-number-of-rows-columns-in-jquery) but have not quite figured out how to adapt it properly to my app's requirements.

If anyone can help me write the function to do this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
var firstYear = 1900;
var lastYear = 1950;
for(var i =firstYear; i<=lastYear; i++) {
       $('#years').append('<li>'+i+'</li>')
}
```

Comment: Note: since you're doing a lot of appends, this will be faster if you first [.detach](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) `#years` from the DOM, then append it when done. See: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/entropo/8EjS7/)

Comment: @entropo thanks for the tip, I'll definitely do that as it's also doing a heap of calculations on load at the same time. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var y=1900; y <= 1950; ++y) 
    $('#years').append('<li>' + y + '</li>');
```

Seen running here: http://jsfiddle.net/qDAVA/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var firstYear = 1900;
  var lastYear = 1950;

  for (var i = firstYear; i++; i <= lastYear) {
    $('<li>' + i + '</li>').appendTo('ol#years');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to generate the number of years in between given the start and stop year?

```
<ul id='years'>
</ul>

var startYear = 1950;
var endYear = 1965;

var $years = $('#years');
for (var i = startYear; i <= endYear; i++) {
    $years.append('<li>' + i + '</li>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
function createYearList(start, end){
    var ul = $('<ul>').appendTo('body');

    for (i = start; i <= end; i++)
    {
        $('<li>').html(i).appendTo(ul);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    createYearList(1900, 1950);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ynhat/ngmNF/